# How to use placeholder in certain parts of predefined array(for later population) and fill

Tags: php, arrays, curl, dictionary, case

Firstly I would like to say I am open for suggestions and this method I am planning to use may not be the best way to tackle the problem.

I am making a wrapper for **CURL** in **PHP**, CURL has many *CURLOPT_** constants that can be set so I have created a simple array to convert a simple keyword which is easy to remember to map to the the fully named *CURLOPT_** constant.

**Example**

```
$map = [
    URL => [
        CURLOPT_URL, %PLACEHOLDER NEEDED%
        ]
    POST => [
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => %PLACEHOLDER NEEDED%
        ]
    ];


$data = [
    URL = 'http://yahoo.com/login',
    POST => '?login=user&pass=pass'
    ];
```

I am looking for a simple way to take/apply the corresponding fields from the **$map** array whilst also inserting the variables from **$data** at the **%PLACEHOLDER%** position.

Ideal result would look like

```
$result = [
    CURLOPT_URL, 'http://yahoo.com/login',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '?login=user&pass=pass'
    ]
```

I can achieve this result through the use of 3-4 nested for loops and and some if statements, but it feels very *"hacky"* and not a good final solution.

Comment: I suggest that you have a look at existing wrappers. Example : https://github.com/shuber/curl